# Iterate a dictionary in dictionary in django template

Tags: python

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "20",
        "user_id": "1865",
        "amount": "100",
        "currency_id": "153",
        "content_ids": "17408",
        "invoice_id": "72f5014243f8d",
        "order_number": "387049404M2007243",
        "gateway_response": "{\"TIMESTAMP\":\"2018-10-08T12:30:17Z\",\"CORRELATIONID\":\"72f5014243f8d\",\"ACK\":\"Success\",\"VERSION\":\"57.0\",\"BUILD\":\"46457558\",\"AMT\":\"100.00\",\"CURRENCYCODE\":\"USD\",\"AVSCODE\":\"Y\",\"CVV2MATCH\":\"S\",\"TRANSACTIONID\":\"387049404M2007243\"}",
        "created_date": "2018-10-24 12:42:55",
        "ordered_on": "Wed, Oct 24th '18",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "content_details": {
            "fid": "17408",
            "id": "4f6b08955b1fc1049cc51869f36b1853",
            "name": "Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse",
            "story": null,
            "content_types_id": "6",
            "app_id": "5",
            "permalink": "carol-of-the-bells-satb-arr-jay-rouse"
        },
        "poster_url": "http://devstudio.cnedocent.com/img/No-Image-Vertical.png",
        "seller_details": {
            "email": "afixi.gayadhar@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Gayadhar khilar"
        },
        "price_details": {
            "price": "100",
            "price_id": "1",
            "code": "USD",
            "symbol": "$"
        }
    },
```

I want to get name in content details from the above json response, but I am unable to iterate it. How to do so?

Comment: What do you mean you can't iterate it? Have you tried `for item in my_dict`?

Comment: If you want to access a specific key, why do you want to iterate at all? Why not simply `my_dict['0']['content_details']['name']`?

Comment: Hello @ChidanandaNayak. Please show us what you tried yet. Your question is being downvoted because we expect that you share your attempts.

Comment: @CorentinLimier yeah i have tried this code but seems like im getting it wrong..
 for i in data['0']:
...     for j in i['content_details']:
...             print(j)

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak please edit your post and add this code, with the error or result you got.

Comment: @CorentinLimier it gives this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992414/iteration-of-dictionary-in-django-template) the same question multiple times. Edit this one if you have more information to provide.

Answer (score 3):

```
import json

strJson = '''
 <your JSON string>
'''

dictJson = json.loads(strJson)

# python 2.X
for key, value in dictJson.iteritems():
    print (value['content_details']['name'])

# python 3.X
for key, value in dictJson.items():
    print (value['content_details']['name'])
```

Comment: Your code won't compile in python3, missing parenthesis

Comment: Actually, unless `distJson` is really long, you can use `items()`, regardless of Python version. Overhead on creating generator object and using its interface is comparable to the cost of creating a list of pairs (key, value).

Answer (score 2):

```
json.load(open("/tmp/j.json"))["0"]["content_details"]["name"]
```

Result:

```
'Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `dict` is the name of the above construct, `dict['0']['contend_details']['name']` is the property you're looking for ("Carol of the Bells SATB - arr. Jay Rouse" in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data["0"]["content_details"]["name"])
```

Comment: why do you use pprint to print a string ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```html
 all_content_details = [your_json[x]['content_details'] for x in your_json.keys()]
 print(all_content_details)
```

This should allow you to iterate though all the content details of your JSON

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like this ?

```
j = json.load(json_string)
for x in j:
    print(j[x]['content_details']['name'])
```

Comment: You should use `json.loads()` to parse a string into JSON. `json.load()` parses a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item, value in d['0']['content_details'].items():
    if item == 'name':
        break
    print(value)
```

Comment: I have following issues with your answer: (1) You assume `d` is of type `dict`, while the question mentions 'json response', so it's likely about parsing JSON into dict rather than iterating over a dict. (2) Your code accesses only the "0" key in the original structure, but we're being asked about 'iterating' over it, so perhaps there's more keys and you should rather iterate over top-level keys and get or print `value["content_details"]["name"]` from each.

Comment: @Abgan ah, ok:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.